# Отправка с сайта запроса на сервер для запуска скрипта и последующего приема файла с сайта

Tags: python, веб-программирование, flutter

В наличие есть flatter веб-приложение, в котором можно ввести различные данные, а также арендованный линукс сервер, на котором находится питон скрипт для расчёта параметров, подскажите как отправить запрос с данными (которые пользователь введет на сайте) на сервер, и затем файл который сгенерирует скрипт отправить в память устройства, которое в данный момент использует сайт